# How to set wordpress automatically featured Image?

Tags: image, wordpress, post, wordpress-featured-image

As my new wordpress themei need a featured image in my post, i don't know How to set wordpress automatically featured Image?

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Answer (score 0):

you can do with easily just upload image and it take image as featured image http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-auto-featured-image/